# How do I 'select' multiple values in a multiple select using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<select ng-model="myData.states" multiple="multiple" ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in myStates">
</select>
```

I populate these options in a controller using ajax.

In some cases, I want to load the page with some options 'selected'.  How do I achieve this if I have the state name? i.e. (CA, TX).  I do not have the value since angular increments the value on its own.

Comment: Just set `$scope.myData = {states:['CA', 'TX']};` It will get selected. http://plnkr.co/edit/WzUENG?p=preview

Comment: Thanks.  This is based on the value, what about if I want to base it off the name.  As I mentioned, I don't know the ID of the state.

Comment: What do you mean by id of the state, how does your data model looks like? you said `How do I achieve this if I have the state name? i.e. (CA, TX)` in your question.

Comment: The ID is an incremental value that angular sets.  Starts with value="0" and up to last value.

Comment: That is the whole purpose of using angular right, you dont worry about what the option value is, instead you will just bind with data and deal with data. Anyways you could set your ngModel to the specific array of codes from the selected index that you get

Comment: Like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/v3K3sI?p=preview

Comment: Actually what I'm saying is if you have the text "Alabama" and you want to select that option. Not the ID or abbreviation.

Comment: It should not be hard right? just set value as state name in ngOption, `ng-options="option.name as option.name ..`. So your ngModel will hold array of state names. Anyways why do you want to set it by name? http://plnkr.co/edit/5SGPAw?p=preview

Comment: That's the value we get from our model.